# change size of visual hints (annotations) on scroll bar

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Having to do some editing work in VS 2015 and finding the annotations in the scroll bar supremely useful (the coloured hints about errors, warnings, break points and so on); however, on an ultra HD monitor, they are also very tiny.

I can't find an obvious option to change their size (width) anywhere. Does anybody know if the size is controllable, maybe editing the vs settings file somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the scroll bar, select Scroll Bar Options, select Use map mode. Maybe it will look better in UHD.